# VMWare Server and Linux NIC Bonding

Tags: linux, vmware-server, bonding

If I am running VMWare server on a Linux host, and the VMs are using bridged network, will the VMs know to failover to the other NIC?  I don't have a clear picture of how VMWare bridged networking actually works.

I still need to go read more about Linux bonding.  My goal is to have a secondary NIC that is failover where the switches do not need to be stacked (Each nic will be connected to a different switch, the switches will be trunked).  So maybe I will ask this in a second question, and it is kind of a bonus question here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly with KVM:

ethX+ethY -> bondX -> bridgeX -> VM

failover happens on the bond level, transparent to the VM

Comment: He was asking about VMWare Server.

Comment: shouldn't be different, just need to use the bond alias instead of the NICs when configuring the bridge there.

Comment: This is how I have my VMWare Server setups configured but honestly I haven't yet tested they behave like we want.

Comment: So I create the bond interface, then re-run configure.pl (whatever that was) and tell it to bridge to the bondX interface (ie bond0) ?

Comment: Not too sure about the vmware bits, I've kept away fir over a year now. but yeah, either via a script, or connect to the GUI, and set up the bridge (or v-switch?) to connect to the bondX interface as the physical NIC it should go out through

Comment: Yes.

I decided today was the day to test the whole bonding thing since I have another customer who wants to run it and it didn't work our right on our first test the other night.

I just tested a CentOS 4.8 host running 1.09 or 1.10 and dual NICs.  Dropping one port at the switch level made the host switch just fine and might not have even dropped a ping.  The guests were not happy.  I suspect it might be that they are running on shared storage via NFS and that's what freaked out.  I had to acknowledge a read error in the VMWare console on most guests to make them happy.

Comment: Testing a non-shared-storage system now.

Comment: After a couple of sidetracks, here's what I found:

Host:  CentOS 4.8 with older kernel 2.6.9-34 and VMware Server 1.10 using local storage.  Dual NICs going to dual switches and running bonding.

Guests:  Win2k3 Web and CentOS 5.4/Apache

Running pings to all 3 machines.  If I down the primary host interface at the switch, the host drops a packet and switches to the secondary.  Both guests drop packets and do not return until they originate outbound traffic, either by themselves or if I log into the console.

Not exactly what we want...

Comment: Rather strange... Can you try the same with virtualbox? This might be specific to the way VMWare interacts with the network. I've already mentioned KVM, but I don't know if your hardware can support it

Comment: Hi Kieth, can you post your bonding config as an example for me?  I will run some tests as well.